# Логирование c TimedRotatingFileHandler

Tags: python

В `Python` есть клевая библиотека с логированием `logging.handlers`, в которой есть класс `TimedRotatingFileHandler` для сохранения информации о логах. Но никак не пойму как сделать так, чтобы при копировании инфомации из логов, лог не содержал больше скопированную из него информацию.

Например, у меня есть такой скрипт:

```
import logging
import os

formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt='%(asctime)s [%(levelname)-8s] %(name)-12s: %(message)s',
                              datefmt='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')


def set_logs(path):
    handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(path,
                                               maxBytes=512000000,
                                               backupCount=4)

    head, tail = os.path.split(path)
    path_to_log_dumps = os.path.join(head, "dumps", tail)

    time_handler = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(path_to_log_dumps,
                                                             when='s',
                                                             interval=5,
                                                             backupCount=4)

    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    time_handler.doRollover()
    time_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    root_logger = logging.getLogger('1c')

    root_logger.addHandler(handler)
    root_logger.addHandler(time_handler)


def get_logs(name):
    name = '1c.' + name
    handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    return logger


if __name__ == '__main__':  
    set_logs('./log/test.log')
    logger = get_logs('handler')

    i = 0
    while True:
        logger.info(str(i) + '. Hello there!')
        i += 1
        time.sleep(1)
```

В папке logs создается файл test.log, а в папке logs/dumps создаются файлы, в которых располагается информация из test.log. Но при этом в файле test.log эта же информация остается.

Например содержимое файла `test.log.2016-08-24_16-55-29` из файла `logs/dumps`:

```
24.08.2016 16:55:29 [INFO    ] 1c.handler  : 15. Hello there!
24.08.2016 16:55:30 [INFO    ] 1c.handler  : 16. Hello there!
24.08.2016 16:55:31 [INFO    ] 1c.handler  : 17. Hello there!
24.08.2016 16:55:32 [INFO    ] 1c.handler  : 18. Hello there!
24.08.2016 16:55:33 [INFO    ] 1c.handler  : 19. Hello there!
```

Но эта же информация осталась и в файле `test.log`, а мне надо, чтобы она удалялась при ротации.

Comment: При копировании откуда? Куда?

Comment: @FeroxTL, дополнил вопрос.

Comment: Ротация, если мне не изменяет память, это когда создаются файлы log.1 log.2, информация из них не удаляется. В линуксах logrotate сам умеет чистить за собой, а вот в питоне такое по-моему не работает